# Problems with adding CSV layers ETRS89 (no latitude/longitude but X and Y coordinates)

Tags: coordinate-system, import, addlayer

I am dealing with some data I need to get on QGIS.  It's CRS should be ETRS89, but instead of 
longitude/latitude I only have X and Y coordinates, and as soon as I add the data as CSV layer it ends up at a place where it should not belong.

I use this CSV here: https://data.gov.uk/dataset/b5d2f859-9a06-47bc-8f09-89171cfe97ba/shropshire-brownfield-site-register
It includes the X and Y coordinates and states it is ETRS89.

Within the CSV I have the coordinates.
CordX: 3853505 and CordY -205876

and it should be ETRS89
but if I look at the area where the points should end up, as ETRS89 the coordinates should be more like.

X: -3.059671 and Y: 52.862264

Is there a way to import the CSV with these coordinates instead? (in QGIS)
Or do I have to convert them prior manually? How do I do that in the best way? (it's a file with a total of ~1500 records).

Comment: those are projected units. it seems the CRS info is incomplete; you might want to give someone a note.  you could try the more obvious projections based on ETRS89, like UTM ([EPSG:25830](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-30n/)), but without the definitive projection details you're stuck...

Comment: ETRS89 is not a CRS

Comment: EPSG:4258 (based on ETRS89) , is lat/lon, so X would be 52...and Y would be -3...

Comment: The following are a list of [ETRS89 based Projected CRS that cover the United Kingdom](https://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3035&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3034&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25828&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3040&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25829&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3041&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2157&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=ETRS89ProjectedCRS-forUnitedKingdom&r=84), the answer is possibly there...

Comment: @nmtoken, are you sure that the CSV driver of QGIS is aware of axis order? I would rather believe that it assumes longitude-latitude or easting-northing always but I may be wrong.

Comment: @user30184 QGIS asks you to specify which column is which, so you can always swap if you have a Lat/long or Northing/Easting projection

Comment: @nmtoken, ETRS89 is a geographic CRS.

Comment: @mkennedy I thought it was a datum on which CRS are based